# Confused about Arguments Passing

Tags: java

I'm a bit confused about information passing to methods in Java. I'm currently studying Java basics on Oracle website and while most things I understand with no problem, some things aren't clear enough to me.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html

Here is where I'm having doubt. When they write the following code...

```
public void moveCircle(Circle circle, int deltaX, int deltaY) {
    // code to move origin of circle to x+deltaX, y+deltaY
    circle.setX(circle.getX() + deltaX);
    circle.setY(circle.getY() + deltaY);

    // code to assign a new reference to circle
    circle = new Circle(0, 0);
}
```

What do they mean by `circle = new Circle(0, 0);`? Is it creating a new Cicle object or what? I think what confuses me is how the object parameter is used inside the method declaration.

Can someone explain to me clearly what Passing reference data types is about?

Comment: That call doesn't make any sense. That new instance will immediately go out of scope, so it doesn't do anything.

Comment: From provided document: "*This reassignment has no permanence, however, because **the reference was passed in by value and cannot change**. Within the method, the object pointed to by circle has changed, but, when the method returns, myCircle still references the same Circle object as before the method was called.*"

Comment: This is example explaining that in Java object references are also passed by value.

Comment: So the new circle(0, 0) is actually useless?

Comment: @TomásDornasPerone in this snippet, yes. It is reassigned to a copy of `circle` passed to method, after all reasonable operation on original `circle` were performed, so will have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Start with a simpler example:

```
public class Main  {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        int x = 7;
        add(x);
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    public static void add(int y){
        y = 10;
    }
}
```

What do you expect this code to print out?

It prints out **7** because even though we're reassigning the parameter received by the `add()` function, **that doesn't affect the original value passed into the function**. The x variable in the `main()` method is still 7.

The example code is just showing you a more complicated example of that with Objects instead of primitives. The lesson you're supposed to learn is that **reassigning parameters in a function does not affect their original values**.

Comment: This is clear for primitive types, but for objects may lead to misunderstanding. People often confuse "object value" (i. e. values of object members) and "object reference value"

Comment: In case it helps, remember that Java always passes by value.  But in the case of objects, the passed value *is* a reference.  So any changes you make to the referenced object will persist after the method call, such as calling setX() on the circle in the original example.  But any changes you make to the passed reference value itself will be lost, such as setting it to null or pointing to another object entirely.

Answer (score 1):

> These changes will persist when the method returns. Then circle is assigned a reference to a new Circle object with x = y = 0. This reassignment has no permanence, however, because the reference was passed in by value and cannot change.

Read the last paragraph carefully. 
You are able to modify the attributes of the referenced circle, but if you assign the variable a new reference, no changes were made to the original object. It only tells `myCircle`to refer to a newly created object. And this object gets immediately garbage collected after the method goes out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation for the two questions you asked:-

1. `circle = new Circle(0, 0)` means that we are assigning values to the constructor of Circle object .
2. Yes this is creating new circle object by passing values to the reference variable `circle`.

Hope it helps!